# Accessing private methods in Java

Tags: java

I have a class which represents a level in my game. I'm writing an AI which needs to be able to predict how the world will react step-by-step to its actions. Those step-by-step simulations are currently handled by private functions, but I would like the AI to be able to make a copy of the instance of the level and access those private functions on that copy.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why are they private if you need to have them accessed publicly?

Comment: Not sure which class is accessing which, but if you really needed to... reflection can do it

Comment: @Dave Newton I don't want other classes to be able to modify the game state in unintended ways.

Comment: @Rizhiy Then as Jérémie B says you should copy the game state and allow the AI to operate on that.

Comment: @DaveNewton copying it doesn't work since the class is still the same.

Comment: @Rizhiy ... You'd have a method that takes in game state and manipulates it.

Answer (score 3):

Short of using reflection, you will need to increase the visibility from private to something which is accessible outside the class.

Consider using package private - this is actually the default visibility modifier, indicated by putting no explicit modifier:

```
class Foo {      // A package private class.
  int bar;       // A package private field.
  void baz() {}  // A package private method.
}
```

Such methods will be visible only to classes in the same package - you can put your AI classes in the same package.

If you don't want third parties to be able to define classes within the same package - which would give them visibility of these methods - you might consider using something like a [sealed jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html).

Comment: Unfortunately due to organizational reasons my classes have to be in a different package.

Comment: @Rizhiy well, your methods have to be public then. But there is no way to stop *any* class calling them then. Such is the java packaging model.

Comment: I found a compromise by making it protected and extending it to my class in my package and redefining the method there, then calling original from extension.

Comment: Sure, but if you can extend the class in your package, I can extend the class in my package, and call all those methods you don't want me to. You may as well just make them public.

Comment: But not on the original instance as far as I can tell, I don't mind if you call the methods on your instances as long as they are not mine.

Comment: @Rizhiy I think you are missing my point: if *you* have a mechanism by which you can call the methods from other packages, then *everybody* does. There is no point in making it harder for yourself.

Comment: I don't mind people calling the method on their own instances, as long as they don't do it on mine.

Comment: @Rizhiy then it's not a question of the visibility, it is a question of not providing access to references to your instances on which to call the methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102295/discussion-between-rizhiy-and-andy-turner).

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection for this. For example,

```
public class PrivateObject {

  private String privateString = null;

  public PrivateObject(String privateString) {
    this.privateString = privateString;
  }

  private String getPrivateString(){
    return this.privateString;
  }
}
```

For this class,

```
PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject("The Private Value");

Method privateStringMethod = PrivateObject.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPrivateString", null);

privateStringMethod.setAccessible(true);

String returnValue = (String) privateStringMethod.invoke(privateObject, null);

System.out.println("returnValue = " + returnValue);
```

Read more [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html).

Comment: your answer is correct, but reflection shouldn't be used for this kind of things. it should be reserved for frameworks or low level library. OP should better models a read-only state object and let his AI access this state

Comment: I was looking more for a design pattern rather then changing the access modifier.

Comment: @Rizhiy  don't think you can access private methods by using any design patterns

Answer (score 0):

Non-reflection answer (because I didn't want to meddle with access at runtime): change access modifier from private to protected, extend the main class and make a new method with public modifier from which the original method can be called.

This way the real level still can't be changed inappropriately and AI can use the required functions.